# Creating a VirtualBox Host-Only instance with an IP that conflicts with the network

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a series of static IP VirtualBox guests that will have IP addresses that will conflict with other machines on the Host's network. I tried to use a Host-Only adapter and set it up with the IP being the first 3 octet's of the Guest's static IP and the last octet being 1. For example, if the Guest IP was `192.168.56.34`, I have the Host-Only adapter's IP set to `192.168.56.1`.

This seems to be mostly working, but its very hit or miss. I'm not sure if I'm just getting lucky and bringing my box up when the other boxes on the network are down or what, but a `tcpdump -i vboxnet0` shows no traffic on the interface on some reboots whereas others it shows no activity. When there is no activity on the interface, I cannot reach the box.

**So my question is**, what is the best way to setup a VirtualBox guest that can have the same IP as another machine on the Host's network but still allow the host to reach the VirtualBox guest (does not need access to the other machine on the network with the same IP)?

The host OS is Centos7.

Comment: Is this just a network just between the host and the guests? If so, why do you need to use the same address range? [Also this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) may be an interesting read

Comment: @Smock The Guest OS I'm installing and bringing up has a fixed IP. If I can use virtualbox to somehow translate that IP to a non-conflicting one that would work too. But the Guest will always have a conflicting static IP. Also, it is a network between just the host and guest. Guest does not need any sort of external connection

Comment: It does look like Host-Only is the type of network that fits best here, but I'm guessing you're having trouble with conflicting IP addresses when you talk about it being hit and miss. If you never need to connect to the other (real?) machines with those IP addresses on that range you could set up [static routes](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-new-static-route-on-rhel7-linux) to always go to the virtual box machines?

Comment: Thats what I was assuming was conflicting IPs but the tcpdump on the host only adapter still shows no traffic sometimes

Comment: Is that because the traffic is trying to route over the adapter that connects it to the original (real?) IP addresses rather than the duplicates?

Comment: No, I am using `curl --interface vboxnet0` and I can see my requests on the `tcpdump` for the interface but I can't see the Guest's traffic on the interface